# Adapting constructor injection - how to go from argument to factory?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

How do I adapt an existing class of the form:

```
public class A
{
    A(IDependency1 obj1, IDependency2 obj2)
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Into something like this:

```
public class A
{
    private List<IDependency2> _things;

    A(IDependency1 obj1)
    {
        _things = new List<IDependency2>();
        foreach (var x in someCollection)
            _things.Add(NewInstanceOf<IDependency2>());
    }
}
```

The key point is that in the first example `obj2` is a singleton instance of `IDependency2`. In the second example an unpredictable number of instances of `IDependency2` are created.

I have considered having a `Func<IDependency2>` parameter in the constructor, but I discussed this with an aquaintance who suggested I use `IDependencyResolver` because it would be more explicit.

Comment: Where would `someCollection` come from in the second example?

Comment: @Servy: That's something that's decided at run time. Does that make a difference to how I would change the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a factory interface like:

```
public interface IDependencyFactory<T> where T : class, new()
{
    T Create();
}
```

And a simple implementation:

```
public class SimpleDependencyFactory<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public T Create()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Then your classes constructor would take the factory as a parameter:

```
public class A
{
    private List<IDependency2> _things;

    public A(IDependency1 obj1, IDependencyFactory<IDependency2> dep2Factory)
    {
        _things = new List<IDependency2>();
        foreach (var x in someCollection)
            _things.Add(dep2Factory.Create());

    }
}
```

This will not compile because of `someCollection` though. Also obj1 is never used in your example. I don't know why you added it in the first place. Note that what's powerfull about factories is that you could add more complicated implementations that didn't simply create an object with a parameterless constructor. Look for different factory patterns. Popular ones are the Factory Method and Abstract Factory.

Comment: Unused elements of code are for the purpose of demonstration. The entire code sample is somewhat contrived, but still demonstrates my point I hope.

Answer (score 2):

In DI the interface acts as a contract about the dependencies. 
as you say there will exist

> an unpredictable number of instances of IDependency2

this screams for me for any kind of injected collection

example:

```
interface IDependency2List
{
    IEnumerable<IDependency2> Items;
}
interface IDependency2
{
    //bla
}
public class A
{
    public A(IDependency1 dep1, IDependency2List dep2List)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: My choice of structure would be that `A` decides how many instances of `IDependency2` to create. That would involve my touching fewer classes.